# Is there a way to change the id parameter automatically when creating a GET request on Postman, rather than manually creating separate requests

Tags: api, scripting, postman, ckan

I am quite new to Postman and I am trying to solve the following problem:

I am using the CKAN api and have found a way to get list of active users and their id
http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/user_list.

I now want to find the last time each user was active using this call http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/user_activity_list?id=

These calls were found on ckan's api guide. https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/api/

Is there a way to update the id parameter with a loop of some sort, so that i dont have to call separate get requests for each id

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
       http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/user_activity_list?id={{id}}
```

Use a variable as I'd , and then update the value from pre request script

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would i go about doing that, still really new to postman. Cheers,